# Continuous (24/7) use of servos OK?

Tags: servo

I'm using a Raspberry Pi, a PCA9685 controller, and a servo to control the air intake lever on my woodstove based on stove and room temperatures. My code adjusts the servo position every 2 minutes and there is no force from the stove lever on the servo except when it's moving to a new position (and the servos were perfectly quiet when idle). The system runs 24/7 and is working great. Except that now two servos have burned out - the first lasted 6 weeks and the 2nd one only 4 (seems the internal electrics failed, all the gears are fine). Are servos designed to be "on" 24/7 for months at a time? If not, is there a way to turn the servo off via the PCA9685 controller to lengthen its lifespan?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104529/discussion-on-question-by-user3217032-continuous-24-7-use-of-servos-ok).

Answer (score 0):

***Answer***

There are a couple of things to prolong servo life:

> (1) Using a switching regulator with a small current limit, say, less
>   than 5009mA, then when the servo is over loaed, get stuck etc. stall
>   current will be small, and therefore not heating up the motor and fry
>   it.
>
> (2) Use Rpi or PCA9685 GPIO pin to switch off eg, the LM2596 switching
>   power supply to save working or idle current.
>
> (3) Do not buy fake servos from eBay.  Instead, buy from authorized
>   distributors.
>
> (4) Move servo in small steps for a smooth travel, therefore reduce
>   abrupt movements causing unnecessarily large current and wear and tear
>   by friction and heat.
>
> (5) Regularly lubricate the stove damper lever to reduce friction and
>   therefore lighten servo work load.
>
> (6) Replace the dc motor and potentiometer (need DIY skill, but they
>   are sort of standard parts, therefore easy job for hobbyists) with
>   good quality ones, before or after burning out, to prolong servo life.

---

***Problem Analysis***

*1. The following wood stove is used as a case study and example for reference.*

*Wood Stove and stove Lever*

I am assuming the OP's wood stove and the stove lever is similar to the picture below.

[image: wood stove]

---

*2. TowerPro MG995 and SG spec are used as references*

[image: sg90 and ms995 servo]

---

*3. MG995 Spec is used to design speed and current for the wood stove servo*

[image: mg995]

---

I am assuming genuine servos are used.

[image: fake mg995]

---

***References***

---

***Appendices***

---